# change BOTTOM toolbar items color

Tags: objective-c, toolbar, ios8.3

I have a simple toolbar on my screen. This toolbar has two items that are buttons. The first should be black and the second blue. Already changed their color the code and the storyboard but when I run the two still black application. How can I change the color only the second item?

this is my toolbar;

[image]

this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.deviceImages.delegate = self;
    self.deviceImages.dataSource = self;
    [self.rigthToolbarItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:82/255.0 green:157/255.0  blue:230/255.0  alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Basically, you have to create a UIButton, configure it as you wish, and then initialize the Bar Button Item with the UIButton as a custom view.
like:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:....];
...(customize your button)...

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

or

**Solution 2:**

To change the color of title: iOS7:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                 target:nil 
                                 action:nil];
[button setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
               [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] 
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

and prior iOS7:

UIBarButtonItem *button = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                  target:nil 
                                  action:nil];
[button setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
               [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] 
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it would help to figure out the solution for your question.